# Adding value="Empty Text" to Search Portlet

Tags: liferay

What I'm simply trying to do is add an empty text string to the Search Portlet Search Bar, basically I want to accomplish this:

```
<div id="myportlet"> //(or however it's rendered)
    <input type="text "id="search" value="Search Here">
</div>
```

Edit: 
Following Pankaj's advice, I placed the `placeholder` tag in each instance of `aui:input`, and restarted my server but have yet to see my changes.

```
<aui:input name="<%= SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR_PARAM %>" type="hidden"  value="<%= ParamUtil.getInteger(request, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR_PARAM, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR) %>" placeholder="Search Portal1"/>
    <aui:input name="format" type="hidden" value="<%= format %>" placeholder="Search Portal "/>

    <aui:fieldset id="searchContainer">
        <aui:input autoFocus="<%= windowState.equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED) %>"  inlineField="<%= true %>" label="" name="keywords" size="30" value="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(keywords) %>" placeholder="Search Portal3"/>

        <aui:input inlineField="<%= true %>" label="" name="search" src='<%= themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() + "/common/search.png" %>' title="search" type="image" placeholder="Search Portal4"/>

        <aui:input inlineField="<%= true %>" label="" name="clearSearch" src='<%= themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() + "/common/close.png" %>' title="clear-search" type="image" placeholder="Search Portal5"/>
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Clay Banks has write well but using jQuery.

In Liferay it's better to use AlloyUI, the js embedded framework bassed on YUI3.

```
<aui:script>

var A = AUI();

A.one('#specific_div input[type="text"]').attr(''placeholder', 'Some Text!');

</aui:script>
```

p.s. check the sintax..

Comment: I've never used AlloyUI, but I will look into it thanks

Comment: Where do I embed this script, in the search.jsp file?

Answer (score 0):

You can override /docroot/html/portlet/search/search.jsp in hook and provide placeholder attribute to  aui input tag of search field.

HTH
Regards

Comment: It's not the best way. It's possible but it's better to use js way for this and not write an hook plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was simply target the input element with some **javascript** and gave it an `.attr()` function, like so:

```
$('#specific_div input[type="text"]').attr('placeholder', 'Some Text!');
```

To me, this is a more efficient process because you can instantiate the search portlet many times in one portal (.vm) using `$theme.search()` and alter each one individually instead of changing the entire search.jsp file.